# How do I get write access to ubuntu files from Windows?

Tags: server, windows-7, virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on my Virtual Machine as a web server. I've mounted the W:/ drive in Win 7 to my /www folder in Ubuntu.

I can read the files, but I'm not able to write to the files.

In Samba, I have created the following user:

```
<www-data> = "<www-data>"
```

And given guest ok for the www folder:

```
[www]
comment = Ubuntu WWW area
path = /var/www
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
;directory mask = 0775
force user = www-data
force group = www-data
```

I've also run `sudo chmod -R 755 www` to make ensure correct rw access.

What am I missing in order to get write access to my ubuntu files from Windows?

Nothing is logged when I try to write to files, even though I get access denied.

Comment: Great, if you got it working, consider answering your question and selecting you answer as the correct. This offers two benefits for the community: 1) People can see what the solution to the issue was, and 2) people will not consume energy trying to answer an already answered question.

Comment: I will once the "waiting time" is over.

Comment: waiting time? You asked the question 22 hours ago, how can it possibly still have waiting time?

Comment: Ah, I thought the check icon would come in my question. Added answer - NOW I have to wait one day :)

Answer (score 1):

After I ran an update (updating Ubuntu, Mambo ++) and once again ran `sudo chmod -R 755 www` I finally got it working.